# Annotation based Spring / JAX-RS integration with no web.xml

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to make a Servlet 3.0 REST server with no web.xml, ie dependent on java classes and annotations only. I'm not exactly sure how I can simultaneously register a Resource class with Spring and with the servlet mappings.

I currently have:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[]{RestServletConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] {"/*"};
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.my.spring.beans", 
               "com.my.spring.services"})
public class RootConfiguration 
{
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.my.resource.classes")
public class RestServletConfiguration
{
}
```

When I start the application, the spring beans are wired correctly, but I'm not sure how to proceed with getting the JAX-RS servlet filter set up correctly. I am currently using Jersey, and haven't been able to find much on the web about integrating Jersey with Spring without using a web.xml.

Does anyone know how to integrate Jersey with Spring in this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can integrate Spring and Jersey in a XML-less mode.

You will need to extend the class `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet`. e.g.:

```java
package org.test;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/rest/*"}, initParams = {
    @WebInitParam(name = "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
            value = "org.test.rest")})
public class JerseyServlet extends SpringServlet {

}
```

Actually, it is a servlet. The parameter `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` indicates where scanning the resources (classes with annotation `@Path`).

The following code is an example of resource:

```java
package org.test.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.test.service.DummyService;

@Path("test")
@Component
public class TestResource {

    @Autowired
    private DummyService service;

    @GET
    public String test() {
        return service.sayHello();
    }

}
```

Such resources need to be scanned by Spring for dependency injection. e.g.:

```java
package org.test.rest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.test.rest")
public class RestConfiguration {

}
```

And this configuration can be loaded by the initializer class. e.g.:

```java
package org.test;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
import org.test.rest.RestConfiguration;
import org.test.service.ServiceConfiguration;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ServiceConfiguration.class, RestConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Maybe you want to see the `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jersey-spring</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The servlet mapping is working, but the utilized Resource has null values for any autowired fields; presumably because it is a different instance of the Resource created by Spring.

Comment: For example, if I put a breakpoint in the test() method on TestResource, then service is null.

Comment: What should be in the getServletConfigClasses() method in the app initializer?

Comment: Also, should the urlPatterns value in the JerseyServlet annotation match the value in the getServletMappings() method on the servlet initializer?

Comment: The injected fields in the resource? Works fine too me. I'm using Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE. BTW, I'm using com.sun.jersey.contribs::jersey-spring::1.18.3 but excluding the dependencies of this.

Comment: Can you add the pom to the answer?

Comment: The other classes: `@Service public class DummyService { public String sayHello() { return "Hello!"; } }` and `@Configuration @ComponentScan("org.test.service") public class ServiceConfiguration { }`. :-)

Comment: I upgraded to the versions you are using and it now works. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: The com.sun...SpringServlet is ditched in the jersey implementation in favor for org.glassfisch...ServletContainer. Does this affect the answer above?

Comment: @PaulVargas: I have a similar question posted. I am positive you will be to help here. please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024735/how-to-wire-jax-rs-service-in-spring-mvc-configuration